# What is the optimal way of declaring variables to optimize Gas in Solidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, gas

Are there any published guidelines on what is the correct order to declare variables in Solidity so that they are optimized from a gas consumption perspective?

Let's say - I need to declare the following variables/types in my smart contract.

```
string public name;
uint128 public largeNum;
bool public isReady;
bytes32 public ticker;
uint64 public score;
enum STATUS {} ;
struct user {};
mapping (address => uint) users
```

What would be the best order to declare these variables?

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1):

By storage packing. Give it a read.
https://www.adrianhetman.com/unboxing-evm-storage/